# Prolog: Filter and list

Tags: list, filter, prolog

> Construct a predicate called fPairsAtoms/3 so that given an atom (first argument), and a list of pairs, unify a third parameter with the filtered list of pairs by selecting only the pairs that have the first component as the atom of the first argument.

Example:

```
fPairsAtoms(sA,[[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]],X)
```

Result:

```
X = [[sA,abbsB],[sA,bb]]
```

I do not understand ..... What should I face these types of exercises?
Can you help me find a solution?

**Today I started with prolog, I am a newbie in every way.**

Comment: If you've just started today, this is a bit too soon. First you should understand what Prolog *terms* are: `atoms`, `Variables`, compound terms `foo(x,X)`. Then you should understand unification, `a = a`, `a = A`, `A = a`, `A = foo(a)`, `foo(A) = foo(a)`, `[atom, B] = [A, bar]`. You should understand lists representation, where

    `[A, B, C] 
    = [A, B | [C]]
    = [A | [B,C]]
    = [A | [B | [C]]]
    = ....
    = [A, B, C | []]`

so that unifying `[A | B] = [a]` *succeeds*, resulting in also unifying `A = a` and `B = []`, but unifying `[A | B] = []` *fails*. etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: This is certainly not a beginner's assignment.

Comment: I suggest that you first try more simpler problems. The above is really not a good fit as a first problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you've just started today, it probably is a bit too soon for you to tackle this problem.

First you should understand what Prolog terms are: `atoms`, logical `Variables`, compound terms `foo(x,X,bar(baz))`.

Then you should understand unification, `a = a`, `a = A`, `A = a`, `A = foo(a)`, `foo(A) = foo(a)`, `[atom, B] = [A, bar]`.

You should understand lists representation, where

```erlang
[  A,   B,   C     ] 
= [A,   B | [C]    ] 
= [A | [B ,  C    ]] 
= [A | [B | [C]   ]] 
= .... 
= [A ,  B ,  C | []]
```

so that unifying `[A | B] = [a]` *succeeds*, resulting in also unifying `A = a` and `B = []`, but unifying `[A | B] = []` *fails*.

Then you need to understand predicates, which under *procedural* interpretation mean,

```erlang
to_prove(This) :- need_to_prove(This) , and_also(That).
```

So that

```erlang
fPairsAtoms(sA, [[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], X) :-
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB],           [sA,bb]].
```

is a perfectly valid, though exceedingly narrow, definition of one.

But then so are also

```erlang
fPairsAtoms(sA, [[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB] | [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]] ], X) :-
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | [           [sA,bb]] ].
% and 
fPairsAtoms(sA, [             [ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB] | [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]] ], X) :-
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | [           [sA,bb]] ].
% and 
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       [sA,abbsB] | [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]] ], X) :-
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | [           [sA,bb]] ].
% and 
fPairsAtoms(sA,                                      [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]]  , Y) :-
            Y =                                      [           [sA,bb]].
% ... and 
fPairsAtoms(sA,                                                        []  , Y) :-
            Y =                                                        [].
```

and so also

```erlang
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       [sA,abbsB] | L                    ], X) :- 
            L =                                      [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], 
            Y =                                      [           [sA,bb]],
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | Y                    ].
```

and thus

```erlang
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       [sA,abbsB] | L                    ], X) :- 
            L =                                      [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], 
            fPairsAtoms( L, Y),
            Y =                                      [           [sA,bb]],
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | Y                    ].
% and
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       [sA,abbsB] | L                    ], X) :-
            L =                                      [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], 
            fPairsAtoms( L, Y),
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | Y                    ].
% and
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       [sA,abbsB] | L                    ], X) :-
            fPairsAtoms( L, Y),
            X = [                       [sA,abbsB] | Y                    ].
% and so
fPairsAtoms(sA, [                       A          | L                    ], X) :-
            A =                         [sA, B   ],
            fPairsAtoms( L, Y),
            X = [                       A          | Y                    ].
% and even
fPairsAtoms(SA, [                       A          | L                    ], X) :-
            A =                         [SA, B   ],
            fPairsAtoms( SA, L, Y),
            X = [                       A          | Y                    ].
```

But on the other hand, in cases were there was no match, we saw that it is

```erlang
fPairsAtoms(SA, [                       A          | L                    ], X) :-
            A =                         [SB, B   ],
            dif( SA, SB),
            fPairsAtoms( SA, L, Y),
            X =                                      Y                     .
% i.e.
fPairsAtoms(SA, [                       [SB, B   ] | L                    ], X) :-
            dif( SA, SB),
            fPairsAtoms( SA, L,                      X)                    .
```

So which one of the two clauses, that we've ended up with,

```erlang
fPairsAtoms( SA, [ [SA, _] | L ], X) :-
            fPairsAtoms( SA, L, Y),
            X = [A |            Y].

fPairsAtoms( SA, [ [SB, _] | L ], X) :-
            dif( SA, SB),
            fPairsAtoms( SA, L,   X).
```

is the right one? The answer is: both!

Answer (score 0):

To filter the pairs in the list, you need to *traverse* it while comparing the given atom with the first element of each pair. A trivial predicate to traverse a list would be:

```
traverse([]).
traverse([Head| Tail]) :-
    traverse(Tail).
```

The predicate in your problem description is terribly named and don't follow recommended Prolog coding guidelines. Let's rename it to `filter_pairs_by_key/3` and change the argument order to `filter_pairs_by_key(Pairs, SearchKey, FilteredPairs)`. Also, the recommended representation for a *pair* in Prolog is `Key-Value`. There are standard predicates  and library predicates that expect this representation (e.g. `keysort/2`). Based on the `traverse/2` predicate template and the code style recommendations, we can write:

```
filter_pairs_by_key([], _, []).
filter_pairs_by_key([Key-Value| Pairs], SearchKey, [Key-Value| FilteredPairs]) :-
     Key = SearchKey, 
     filter_pairs_by_key(Pairs, Atom, FilteredPairs).
filter_pairs_by_key([Key-_| Pairs], SearchKey, FilteredPairs) :-
     Key \= SearchKey, 
     filter_pairs_by_key(Pairs, SearchKey, FilteredPairs).
```

Note that I'm using two clauses for the non-empty list case: one when the pair key matches the atom and one when the match fails.

Sample call:

```
| ?- filter_pairs_by_key([basA-absAb,ab-bbsA,sA-abbsB,bsA-sAsB,sA-bb], sA, FilteredPairs).          

FilteredPairs = [sA-abbsB,sA-bb] ? 

yes
```

More can be said about this problem and this particular solution but, as mentioned in the comments, this is not a beginners exercise. Consider the comments recommendations and after being comfortable with Prolog list notation play with this solution.