# Prolog: facts and rules

Tags: list, prolog, rules, fact

I have the following situation, I have to make a predicate that represents a doctor attending a patient, but it does not work.

```
doctor(adele).
doctor(inez).
doctor(elin).

patient(aurora).
patient(mandy).
patient(roan).

doctor_attends_patient(doc,pat):-doctor(doc),patient(pat).
```

When making the query returns false.

```
doctor_attends_patient(adele,roan).
false
```

Comment: Variables must be capitalized in Prolog. This is page 1 type stuff, please reread your introductory materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [was said before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650698/849891), *predicates* can be read as

```
to_prove(This) :- need_to_prove(This) , and_also(That).
```

so

```
doctor_attends_patient(doc, pat) :- doctor(doc), patient(pat).
```

means that to prove

```
doctor_attends_patient(doc, pat)
```

Prolog needs to prove

```
                                    doctor(doc), patient(pat).
```

Both of these sub-goals are *ground*, do not contain any logical `Variables`, so to be *proven* they must match some *fact(s)* in our knowledge base. But we only have

```
doctor(adele).
doctor(inez).
doctor(elin).

patient(aurora).
patient(mandy).
patient(roan).
```

We do not have `doctor(doc)` nor `patient(pat)` as stated facts.

`doctor(Doc)` on the other hand, *would* match *any* of the stated `doctor/1` facts, because `Doc` is a logical variable able to assume any value.

As [Daniel Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812818/daniel-lyons) points [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699080/prolog-facts-and-rules/53700402#comment94253969_53699080), variable names are *Capitalized*, in Prolog.

You can now fix your predicate definition.

---

As to your query,

```
doctor_attends_patient(adele,roan)
```

also does not match any facts nor rule heads in your knowledge base. The only rule with remotely matching head you have is

```
doctor_attends_patient(doc, pat) :- doctor(doc), patient(pat).
```

but the compound term

```
doctor_attends_patient( adele, roan)
```

does *not* match the compound term

```
doctor_attends_patient( doc  , pat )
```

because though the *functors* of both terms, `doctor_attends_patient`, do match, and their *arities*, *2*, match also, none of the *arguments* inside the parentheses match. In particular,

```
    adele = doc
```

fails, and also

```
    roan = pat
```

would also fail, if tried.

But if you were using *variables*, then

```
    adele = Doc , roan = Pat
```

would instead *succeed*, resulting in a *substitution* `Doc = adele , Pat = roan`. Since the rule's head would then match too, as a whole,

```
doctor_attends_patient(adele,roan)
doctor_attends_patient( Doc , Pat)
```

the rule's body would be entered, and Prolog would try to prove the resulting sub-goals *after* substituting any variables therein with their values in the successful substitution.

You can now fix your predicate definition.